# Помогите исправить код, не понимаю, почему не работает. c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class A {
  public: 
    void f(int i){
       cout<<"A::"<<i<<endl;
    }
    void f(double i){
       cout<<"A::"<<i<<endl;
    }
};
class B: public A{ 
    void f(){
       cout<<"B::"<<endl;
    }
    void f(int i){
       cout<<"B::"<<i<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
  A *p=new B; 
  p->f();
}
```

Сижу изучаю классы, но не понимаю, почему не работает.

Comment: через  A*  вы можете обращаться к членам А , но никак к членам производных классов.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan т.е. адресная магия теряется и явно кастануть обратно нельзя?) или я неверно понял код и по факту создается A?

Comment: Нет,, по факту создается В, но он построен на объекте типа А, и именно к этому объекту вы обращаетесь через указатель на А. Представьте, что В есть А + часть. Кастануть обратно можно  и нужно, если хотите получать В*

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вы меня не совсем поняли, разве нет способа сказать что вот по этому адресу (который p ) хранится на самом деле класс B и вызвыть уже его метод.... хотел быстро пример показать но не нашел компилятора делфи под рукой, там это точно было возможно....

Comment: Если вы обращаетесь к В через A*, то вы намереваетесь  воспринять В как А(вам так нужно). С какой стати  компилятор будет выполнять что то другое?

Comment: Очень похоже, что автор хочет узнать о virtual, а не знает, что такое есть

Comment: Если что я не автор вопроса но так и не понял, есть ли в плюсах способ того что пытался изобразить автор, а именно получение доступа к классу по его адресу(разыменовывая указатель), и как это провернуть? =))

Comment: @ARHovsepyan запись вот такого меня интересует на си или плюсах, это возможно? https://pastebin.com/3nDGc6eg https://ibb.co/rwRtQpr

Comment: Да, можно. И я написал как. Но можно и явный каст. Все зависит от конкретных желаний

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример:

Допустим вы определили класс **Ящик** и его производный класс **Компьютер**, который может вычислять кроме того, что он ящик. Вы создали компьютер и обращаетесь к нему как ящик. И вы где то говорите  "`пусть ящик вычисляет`". И на что это похоже?.. Для такого в С++ существуют виртуальные методы, и если вы хотите, чтобы  при обращении к компьютеру как к ящику, можно было выполнить вычисление, то для ящика вы должны  объявить соответствующий виртуальный метод, таким образом заранее  устанавливая, что ящик может и вычислять:

```
struct Box {
    virtual void compute() {}
};
struct Computer : Box{
    void compute() { cout << 3 * 2; }
};

void foo(Box* pb)
{
    pb->compute();
}
```

Какой Box вы передадите в функцию, еще не известно, главное, что он имеет этот метод и указатель на таблицу виртуальных функции, который укажет на метод Computer::compute, при вызове   pb->compute() как только вы в функцию передадите Computer, таким образом присваивая pb = new Computer. Этот механизм не имеет отношение к вопросу, но зато дает понять, что разные намерения  выполняются разными механизмами. Но, в любом случаи, обращение к `В` как `А` означает, что вам достаточно видеть его таким, и члены `А`(не важно виртуальные они или нет) достаточны для выполнения всех операций. Естественно, что через объект(указатель) производного класса можно обращаться к членам(не закрытым) базового, поскольку он унаследовал их, следовательно имеет эти члены.

Answer (score 1):

Код вполне рабочий, а ошибка достаточно банальна, и заключается в строке:

```
A *p=new B;
```

Вы привели объект класса B к A, в котором просто напросто не определен метод f() без параметров. Чтобы код заработал необходимо заменить строку вызова метода, передав значение int или double:

```
p->f(3);
```

Если же вы хотите обратиться к методам класса B то надо во-первых сделать их публичными как в классе A, во-вторых не приводить объект к классу A:

```
class B: public A{ 
    public:
    void f(){
    cout<<"B::"<<endl;
    }
    void f(int i){
    cout<<"B::"<<i<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
B *p=new B; 
p->f();
}
```