# Магия указателей

Tags: c++, delphi

Навеяно вопросом [Помогите исправить код, не понимаю, почему не работает. c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1414144/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-c)

На делфи такой фокус проворачивается достаточно легко, если я верно понимаю что происходит... но как это провернуть на плюсах?

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  A = class
    procedure f(i :Integer);overload;
    procedure f(i :string);overload;
  end;
  B = class(A)
    procedure f();overload;
    procedure f(i :string);overload;
  end;
  C = class
  end;

procedure A.f(i: integer);
begin
  Writeln('A::');
end;
procedure A.f(i :string);
begin
  Writeln('A::string');
end;

procedure B.f();
begin
  Writeln('B::');
end;
procedure B.f(i :string);
begin
  Writeln('B::string');
end;

var
  p: C;
begin
  p := C(@B.Create);
  B(@p).f();
  B(@p).f(0);
  B(@p).f('');
  A(@p).f('');
  Readln;
end.
```

Вывод:

```
B::
A::
B::string
A::string
```

Comment: Непонятно, причём здесь связанный вопрос. В С++ преобразование класса B к классу С возможно только через `reinterpret_cast`, и это будет грязный хак. А простое восходящее преобразование, которое необходимо применить в связанном вопросе, можно сделать через `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Здесь нет преобразования. Здесь взятие типа по адресу p- хранилка адреса в памяти к экземляру класса B.

Comment: В делфи,в отличии от с++, все классы имеют предком TObject. Поэтому подобное компилируется. Но вот суть кода от меня уплывает

Comment: Не могу понять как `B(@p).f(0);` становится вызовом `procedure A.f(i: integer)`

Comment: @KoVadim, да я в курсе про общего предка, но сути это не меняет, опустим момент с классом C, как провернуть трюк если P будет типом A, и по факту вести к экземпляру класса B
Суть примерно в таком, но это просто синтетический пример.... ```var p: array of A; p[0]:= B.Create(); p[1]:=C.Create;..... if (@p) is A then A(@p).f() else if(@p) is B then B(@p).f()```

Comment: Вы знаете, что такое virtual/override в с++?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов в моем коде такого и не происходит, там последовательно вызовы 
```B.f();``` затем  ```B.f(0);``` которая наследуется из класса A, потом вызов ```B.f('');``` которая перекрывает ```A.f('')```, а потом явный вызов оригинального метода наследованного из A -> A(@p).f('');

Comment: @KoVadim Да, примерно тоже самое что в делфи, здесь нет виртуала, тут перекрытие медода а не переопределение. вы говорите про вот такой вариант, но у него немного иное поведение, вот пример как поведет себя такой класс если я буду переопределять один из методов(virtual; override;) https://pastebin.com/BfbxV7na

Comment: ну вот Ваш код переписанный один в один https://pastebin.com/EzcFmHvQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В С++ нужно явно выразить для объекта какого типа вызывается (не виртуальная)функция .

```
struct A {
    void f(int) 
    {  cout << "A::\n" ;  }
    void f(std::string)
    {  cout << "A::string\n";  }
};
struct B : A {
    void f() 
    {  cout << "B::\n"; }
    void f(std::string) 
    {  cout << "B::string\n" ;  }
};

int main() {
    B* p = new B;
    //B::f()
    p->f();
    //создать А по B*, чтобы вызвать А::f(int)
    A(*p).f(0);
    //B::f(string)
    p->f("");
    //создать А по B*, чтобы вызвать А::f(string)
    A(*p).f("");
    //освободить участок памяти
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```B* p = new B;``` не то :) в моем примере тип переменной ```p``` не имеет отношения ни к классу ```A``` ни к классу ```B```, но пусть будет как в исходном вопросе ```A* p = new B;```, в обратную сторону (из наследника вызвать родителя), как у вас в примере - сложностей не вызывает, речь про вызов класса по адресу в памяти.

Comment: вы просто не можете правильно формулировать вопрос. Отредактируйте так, чтобы был ясен смысл вашего вопроса.

Comment: Мой вопрос с ночи не изменился, как в си записать взятие объекта класса по указателю(как сделать указатель нетипизированным),  в моем примере именно тот код который я хотел бы понять как записать на си\плюсах, я хз, если прям совсем упростить в делфи есть типизированный указатель, и нетипизированный, как имея типизированный указатель, получить нетипизированный, и явно задать тип нетипизированного указателя :) https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi), кстати да, на асме по идее это можно провернуть, вставки ассемблера в плюсах имеются вроде?

Comment: С++ язык строго типизированный. Не типизированный указатель есть void*. Для обращения к конкретному типу объекта, нужно будет кастить:  void* p = new B;
    static_cast<B*>(p)->f(); и т.д.  Если ваш  вопрос с ночи не изменился , и вас все равно не понять, то наверное нужно попытаться оформить вопрос так, чтобы он был конкретным и понятным для тех, кто не в курсе чего вы добиваетесь.  Если я напишу ответ на армянском, суть ответа не изменится, только вы не поймете. Точно также вы оформляете вопрос, ссылаясь на код из другого языка, но суть вашего вопроса все так же не понятна.

Comment: Да, вот то что нужно, поправите вопрос чтоб я его принял?

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, ввиду того, что такое применение не имеет смысла(не будет полезен для других участников),  не буду вносить изменения в ответе.  Ценю ваше стремление отблагодарить принятием ответа, но в данном случаи единственно главное, что ваша проблема решена.